# ActionListener between classes?

Tags: java, swing, jdbc, jbutton, actionlistener

i got promt.java and gui.java files. once i click on OK button on promt it will disappear and run db query. i wanted to get the query result on JTextField on gui.java tried SetText and append from the promt.java but didn't work. its getting the query result to a variable inside the promt but not getting it in gui.

Promt Actionlistener for OK Button

```
try{
            Class.forName(jdbc_driver);
            con=DriverManager.getConnection(db_url, "root", "");
            ps=con.prepareStatement(sql);
            rs=ps.executeQuery();
            if(rs.next());{
                i = 1;
                id=rs.getString("id")+"";
                ovog=rs.getString("ovog")+"";
                ner=rs.getString("ner")+"";
                cardnum1=rs.getString("card_number")+"";
                val=rs.getString("dvn")+"";
                GUI guu=new GUI();
                guu.screen3.setText("id: "+id +"   "+"ovog"+ovog+"   "+"ner"+ner+"   "+"card number"+cardnum1+"   "+"dun"+val);
            }}

            catch(Exception e){
                System.out.println("Not Found!");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

GUI Actionlistener

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    if(e.getSource()==card){
        Cardpromt cp=new Cardpromt();
        cp.prompt();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Creating a new GUI int the `Propmpt` call isn't going to do anything for you, as you are creating a new reference of the GUI class, not the current running one.

What you *can* do though is pass a reference of the current GUI to the `Prompt` when it's created. Better case would be to use an interface with a method to set the text and `GUI` can implement it. Something like

```
public interface GuiService {
    public void setScreenText(String text);
}

public class GUI implments GuiService {
    private JLabel screen;

    @Override
    public void setScreeenText(String text) {
        screen.setText(text);
    }
    ...
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        CardPrompt promt = new CardPrompt(GUI.this);
        prompt.prompt();
    }   
}

public class CardPropmt {
   private GuiService guiService;

   public CardPrompt(GuiService guiService){
       this.guiService = guiService;
   }

   ...
   try {
       ...
       guiService.setScreenText("id: "+id +"   "+"ovog"+ovog+"   "+"ner"+ner+"   "+"card number"+cardnum1+"   "+"dun"+val);
   }
}
```

This way you have a reference to the current GUI class and access to it's method `setScreenText` via the service method.